How to perform band structure calculation of a bulk, nonmagnetic superconductor with spin-orbit coupling using vasp?
I'm new to VASP and I'm trying to calculate the band structure of a bulk, nonmagnetic superconductor with a tetragonal crystal structure. I'm including spin-orbit coupling (SOC) in my calculation using LSORBIT=True.
The VASP manual mentions that LSORBIT=True also sets LNONCOLLINEAR=True automatically. However, my material is nonmagnetic. I'm confused about the following:
LNONCOLLINEAR: What does it mean by "noncollinear magnetic calculations"? Is this relevant for my nonmagnetic case?
MAGMOM: Since my material is superconducting and nonmagnetic, should I use the MAGMOM tag? if yes then how?
Any clarification or advice on setting up the INCAR file for this scenario would be greatly appreciated!

I wrote  some text on spin-orbit coupling and non-collinear magnetism a while ago: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2469/whats-the-difference-between-spin-unpolarized-spin-polarized-and-non-colinear/3558#3558 Please have a look at it. In short: Spin-orbit coupling can cause non-collinear magnetism. At least the formalism allows that. That is why some codes strictly connect the two together, even if that is not needed for some material that has to be investigated.
